# Combining multiple text fields into one in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a list of users in a table, with separate fields for first, middle, and last name. For various reasons, I need to change the database structure such that there is only one "name" field. What is the best/easiest way to migrate my data from the 3 old fields into my one new field?

Comment: You're not using MYSQL??? The accepted answer does not work in MySQL for 2 reasons - MySQL uses `CONCAT()`, not `+`, MySQL uses `IFNULL` not `ISNULL`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First add a column that is longer than all 3 combined.

```
alter table tbl add fullname varchar(100);
```

Next, update it with the [concatenation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) of the old columns.

```
update tbl set fullname = concat(lastname, ', ', firstname, ' ', middlename)
```

(This ends up in the form 'Kirk, John M')

Then, remove the old columns

```
alter table tbl drop column firstname;
alter table tbl drop column middlename;
alter table tbl drop column lastname;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE Users SET FullName = FirstName + ' ' + MiddleName + ' ' + LastName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Users SET Fullname = CONCAT(Firstname, " ", MiddleName, " ", LastName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate using 
'expression + expression'
The expressions should be non-NULL.